# Why new submission deletes event of the previous submission in google script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The first submission works perfectly fine, and when the first submission is edited, it will successfully delete and create new event in the calendar; However:

1. The next submission  will delete event from previous submission.
2. The next submission will still create new event in the assigned
   calendar. This is the updateCalendar() function:

So first conflicts within calendar will be checked (to prevent double booking) This is the function

```
// Check for appointment conflicts
function getConflicts(request){
  var conflicts = request.calendar.getEvents(request.date, request.endTime);
  if (conflicts.length > 0) {
    request.status = "conflict";
  } else {
    request.status = "approve"
  }
  };
```

This is the updateCalendar() function (the one that will create or delete event in the calendar)

```js
    function updateCalendar(request) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,13);
var values = range.getDisplayValues(); 
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('c_qsk903qma3b8mp5ensa7bvvg4k@group.calendar.google.com');
var numValues = 0;
getConflicts(request);
Logger.log(request.status);
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {   
  if (request.status == "approve") {      
        if (values[i][12] == '' || values[i][12] == undefined) {
          var newEvent = calendar.createEvent("booked", request.date, request.endTime);
          var newEventId = newEvent.getId().split('@')[0];
          sheet.getRange(i+2,13).setValue('y');
          sheet.getRange(i+2,12).setValue(newEventId);
          break;
        } else if (request.status == "conflict" && values[i][12] == 'y') {
            var eventEditId = calendar.getEventSeriesById(values[i][11]);
            eventEditId.deleteEventSeries();
            getConflicts(request);
            if (request.status == "approve") {
            var newEvent = calendar.createEvent("booked", request.date, request.endTime);
            var newEventId = newEvent.getId().split('@')[0];
            sheet.getRange(i+2,13).setValue('y');
            sheet.getRange(i+2,12).setValue(newEventId);
            break;
            }
        }
}
    i++;
}
};
```

And this is the main function that will be triggered on form submit

```
function main(){
  var request = new Submission(lastRow);
  getEndTime(request);
  getConflicts(request);
  updateCalendar(request);
  draftEmail(request);
  sendEmail(request);
};
```

This is the screenshot of what it looks like in google sheets
[image]

Comment: Can you explain whit steps what you are trying to do? For us to accurately reproduce your situation? Please see [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you for the reply,
-> I want to create calendar-form system in which user can submit and edit their booking time 
-> If there is another user want to book within the same time period, it will notify the user that its schedule has conflict with other (hence "Conflict" Status)
-> My current code I uploaded will instead delete the event from previous submission and create new event, (even thou the status is "Conflict")

Answer (score 0):

The typo:

```
if (request.status = "Approve")
```

I'm sure it should be:

```
if (request.status == "Approve")
```

And probably it's better to use `.toLowerCase()` method for such cases, just to be safe:

```
if (request.status.toLowerCase() == "approve")
```

And, perhaps, there should be "Approve**d**"?

Comment: Hi Yuri, thanks for the answer, I have tried your method, but the next submission will still delete previous event while creating new one. Maybe it is because of the for() loop problem?

Comment: Did you try to change `=` with `==`?

Comment: yes, I have tried changing [=] with [==], but it will still delete event from previous submission. I have also tried changing [=] to [==] in the getConflicts() function (I just attached it in the original post.

Comment: Nevertheless I'd advice you to fix `=` in your question. This is an error anyway. So, could you paste the line `Logger.log(request.status);` after the line `getConflicts(request);` and show what you get in the log messages? Just to be sure that all previous functions work fine and request.status is not 'Approve' always.

Comment: I have changed /=/ to /==/ and this is what appears after I put logger.log(request.status); after getConflicts

7:55:02 PM Info conflict

Comment: I have also changed the "Approve" and "Conflict" to lowercase (I have updated the code in the original post)

Comment: Honestly when I changed it to [==], I cannot edit the submission, it will always give up "conflict" status, but when I keep it to [=], it could edit the submission perfectly. 
However, when I submit new submission, it will delete previous event while adding new one to the calendar (even when there is no conflicting schedule at all)

Comment: Sorry, I hardly can follow your logic. Statement `if (a=b)` is always True. It isn't a proper statement condition at all. If something works wrong after you fixed this statement to `if (a==b)` it means a bad news for the algorithm a whole. I don't understand why you need the `break` -- it halts the loop immediately after first iteration. I'm afraid It's too much even for me. You need to learn to use `Logger.log` to keep track your variables, etc.

Comment: Ahh, I see, maybe it is because of the "break"? anyway, thank you for the reply, I got some hints already, will continue fixing this issue. I will also share the code here in case I fix it. I will also start using logger.log() as you adviced. Once again, much appreciated.